# change color and size of qwtSlider

Tags: qt, qwt

I would like to change the colors of the handle of a qwtSlider. Also I would like to set the size of the slider-bar itself. I know I can use setBackgroundStyle(), but I would like to specify the size and color of all parts myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible using Qt Stylesheets (although I'd love to be proven wrong).

To change the colors of the handle of a `QwtSlider` you can subclass it and reimplement void `drawThumb(...)` The code of `qwt_slider.cpp` shows how/which colors are chosen.

Analogously you can change other appearance properties by reimplementing other functions from `QwtSlider`.

Comment: Would I have to change the Painter, Brush or Palette in order to change the color?

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation of `qDrawShadePanel`: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdrawutil-h.html. You'll see that you have to pass a QPalette instance which contains groups of colors.